# How to hide animated subplots in a canvas

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, tkinter, subplot

I am writing a gui with tkinter in python to display some plots. The plots have to be animated, because the datasets update every few seconds.
Currently i have 4 plots in a frame.

I want a menu or button or something there that provides the possibility to hide one of those plots, and expands the other plot in the row/column. But even the hiding of one subplot isn't working. Here's my code:

```
class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=self.menu)

        self.filemenu = tk.Menu(self.menu)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label = 'View', menu = self.filemenu)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label = 'Turn on graph 1', command=self.dummy0)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label = 'Turn off graph 1', command=self.dummy1)

        fpath = '../files/somefile.txt'

        self.fig = Figure(figsize = (12, 8), tight_layout = True)
        gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)
        self.ax0 = self.fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
        self.ax2 = self.fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
        self.ax3 = self.fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.frame)
        ani0 = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval = 1000, fargs = (self.ax0, fpath, 'TankDruck O2', 60))
        ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval = 1000, fargs = (self.ax1, fpath, 'TankDruck N2', 60))
        ani2 = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval = 1000, fargs = (self.ax2, fpath, 'TankStand O2', 60))
        ani3 = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval = 1000, fargs = (self.ax3, fpath, 'TankStand N2', 60))
        self.canvas.show()
        #self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)

    def dummy0(self):
        self.ax0.set_visible(True)

    def dummy1(self):
        self.ax0.set_visible(False)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def animate(self, i, ax, path, var, tstep):
        reader = Reader(path)
        reader.read(var, tstep)
        xdata, ydata, var, unit = reader.get_data()
        ax.clear()
        ax.set_ylabel(var + ' in ' + unit)
        ax.set_xlabel('Seconds since 01.01.2000')
        ax.plot(xdata, ydata)
```

When i execute this, it works just fine. Just when i want to hide the subplot then, the program throws an error, but continues running:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
  return self.func(*args)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 531, in callit
  func(*args)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 363, in idle_draw
  self.draw()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 348, in draw
  FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
  self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 966, in draw
  self.tight_layout(renderer, **self._tight_parameters)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1605, in tight_layout
rect=rect)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 352, in get_tight_layout_figure
  pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 131, in auto_adjust_subplotpars
  fig.transFigure.inverted())
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 1049, in __init__
  assert bbox.is_bbox
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_bbox'
```

Does anyone know how i could deal with this? In the best case the plot ax0 would disappear, and ax1 would expand to fill the whole row.
Or do i need to use multiple canvas' or something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution by myself. The problem was the tight_layout of the figure. I changed the call to:

```
self.fig = Figure(figsize = (12, 8))
```

and now it works properly.

I also changed dummy0 and dummy1:

```
def dummy0(self):
    self.ax0.set_visible(True)
    self.ax1.change_geometry(2,2,2) 
    self.canvas.draw()

def dummy1(self):
    self.ax0.set_visible(False)
    self.ax1.change_geometry(2,1,1)
    self.canvas.draw()
```

so the other plot will fill the row. Just in case someone will need this in future, too.

Bye.